# Updating own profile image - Unable to convert BLOB to string

Tags: android, profile, contactscontract

Following code runs mostly successfully but on some devices it crashes and produces the appended error. Any ideas why or what I could do to solve this?

**Code**

```
byte[] photo = ...; 
long rawId = ...;
Uri currentImageUri = ...; // retrieved via ContactsContract.Profile.PHOTO_URI
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawId);
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo);
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

if (currentImageUri != null) {
    // this crashes sometimes, very rarely though
    context.getContentResolver().update(
        Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
        values,
        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = " + rawId + " and " + ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " = 1",
        null);
} else {
    // we need an insert here, this always works without problems
}
```

**Exception**

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
#################################################################
Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string
#################################################################
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:572)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1678)
    ... <MY CODE ABOCE - ContentResolver.update line>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update selection says: "update all data rows in the user's profile uri that have `RAW_CONTACT_ID` equals X and `IS_SUPER_PRIMARY` is true".

That means you're basically overriding all phone, email, organization, address, etc. rows in `Data` table of that profile, making them all `Photo` rows with the specified photo bytes[].

You need to first figure out if the profile already contains a photo, if so, update that specific photo row. If it doesn't contain a photo, you need an insert operation (and not an update).

Check my related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660583/819355
Just modify the code to update the profile uri instead of a contact uri.

Comment: So basically adding the mimetype to to the where clause in case that the profile already has an image should do the trick? I'm already using an insert in the case that the profile does not have an image yet, just left the code away as this one is working fine always...

Comment: yeah, that might cause unexpected consequences in the update flow, which can lead to the error

Comment: actually, you should also remove the "SUPER_PRIMARY" restriction from the where clause. you want to override that photo in any case.